# How to delete wrong predictions after implementing KNN in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, knn

I want determine if each element of the testData set is equal to the prediction of KNN, and if it's different, delete that case, and create a new set of data containing only the cases where KNN predicted correctly.

Is like deleting the wrong predictions of KNN, so I only have the correct ones.

I think I can compare:  Class against testData by index, and If I find different values, delete that row.

What would be an efficent way to do it?

This is the code (I recieved help from user @Rijul with this):

```
trainData= [148.0,50.0,0; ...
            187.0,34.0,0; ...
            204.0,89.0,0; ...
            430.0,161.0,1; ...
            427.0,22.0,1; ...
            -42.0,469.0,1 ...
            ];

testData=   [290.0,-57.0,0; ...
            194.0,-80.0,0; ...
            174.0,33.0,0; ...
            465.0,691.0,1; ...
            270.0,-194.0,1; ...
            -56.0,665.0,1];

% Data
Sample=testData(:,1:2);
Training=trainData(:,1:2);
Group=trainData(:,3);

% Classify
k=1;  % number of nearest neighbors used in the classification
Class = knnclassify(Sample, Training, Group,k);

% Display Prediction
fprintf('%.1f %.1f - Real %d , Predicted %d\n',[testData.'; Class.']);

testLabel=testData(:,3);
cp = classperf(testLabel,Class);
cp.CorrectRate*100
```

> I think what I'm trying to achieve is called ENN Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to the end of the given program. This will generate new test data `testDataNew` with all the rows which failed during classification removed.

```
testDataNew=testData;
for classIndex=length(Class):-1:1
    if(testLabel(classIndex)~=Class(classIndex))
        testDataNew(classIndex,:)=[];
    end
end
```

Here is another alternative

```
testDataNew=testData;
failedIndexes=testLabel~=Class;
testDataNew(failedIndexes,:)=[];
```

Both of them will give the same result.